# Will RaspiOS Lite (no Desktop environment) be able to start a software with GUI made with Tkinter?

Tags: pi-zero-w, raspbian-lite, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-buster

The question might have an obvious answer. I believe it is not possible but I am not able to test it myself on the Rpi zero W until next week. I assume Tkinter requires a “window manager” from an OS that has a desktop environment. Is there a workaround to starting a Tkinter program directly from the terminal, other than installing the raspios desktop environment? I am trying to keep the system as light as possible and preferably auto start the program on boot. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I don't think tkinter can start unless there is a window manager

Comment: Wrong -- but I will write an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assume Tkinter requires a “window manager” from an OS that has a desktop environment.

To clarify a few terms that have a specific technical meaning in GNU/Linux based operating systems:

- **Window(ing) system**: Software that provides the basis of a desktop GUI, which is mostly about relationships with the kernel and hardware. The predominant windowing system in GNU/Linux (including Raspbian/RpiOS) is [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).  It also, as the name implies, provides a simple interface to draw on a 2D surface including rectangular windows in which an application can run, and a HID interface (human input device, eg. mice and keyboards).  The "2D surface" can include multiple desktops, screens, etc.

  Running a TkInter does require this, but it is probably not what you think it is.  If you run bare X without a window manager, you get a black screen with a small white "X" shaped mouse pointer. There is then no way to do anything other than move the X around.  However, you can script it to run applications when it starts, including a window manager (and/*or* your TkInter app)...
- **Window manager:** Software that provides a fancier interface by adding things like window borders, titlebars, etc.  Sometimes these also provide menus and taskbars and can be run alone, although normally they are integrated into a desktop environment.  Examples of window managers (abbreviated WM) are fvwm2, fluxbox, kwin, and openbox (which I am pretty sure is the default used with Raspbian).
- **Desktop Environment:** Software that provides hefty top level things such as a file browser, taskbars and menus, app widgets, etc.  On Raspbian this is an LXDE (their names often end in DE) spin-off that used to be called PIXEL but now seems not to have any name.

You don't need the last two, although a WM might end up being useful.  You can start X running a single application full screen, which I think is what you want.   If you auto-login this at boot it's called a *kiosk* and you'll find lots of discussion on that here and elsewhere.

The basic technique to running a single application is to put it in an `.xinit` file.  You can then start the GUI from a console with the `startx` command.  If you look around for information about these (`startx` and `xinit`) you will find enough of it.

You do not need to use the Raspbian/RpiOS desktop version to do this.  You can start with the lite version and install X.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Was like going back to school! :D I now have some better understanding on how to get it working!

Comment: A vastly under-appreciated answer methinks.